# How do I insert a time value in Redshift in a time column?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Given the following query
`ALTER TABLE public.alldatatypes ADD x_time time ;`,
how do I insert a value into `x_time`?

**Time** appears to be a valid column type according to the documentation.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html#r_Datetime_types-time
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html

However, when I try to do an insert, I always get an error.

Insert query: `insert into public.alldatatypes(x_time) values('08:00:00');`

Error:

> SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: Amazon Invalid operation:
> Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on
> Redshift tables.;

I do not want to use another column type.
I am testing all the column types defined in the documentation.

Comment: Related: [Redshift Time Datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63668345/174777)

Answer (score 0):

That cryptic error message is the one Redshift gives when you try to use a leader-only function as source data for a compute node.  So expect you aren't showing the exact code you ran to generated this error.  I know that it can seem like you didn't change anything important to the issue but you likely have.

You see `select now();` works just fine but `insert into <table> select now();` will give the error you are showing.  This is because now() is a leader only function.  However `insert into <table> select getdate();` works great - this is because getdate() is a function that runs on compute nodes.

Now the following SQL runs just fine for me:

```
create table fred (ttt time);
insert into public.fred(ttt) values('01:23:00'); -- this is more correctly written values('01:23:00':time)
insert into public.fred(ttt) select getdate()::time;
select * from fred;
```

While this throws the error you are getting:

```
insert into public.fred(ttt) select now()::time;
```

So if this doesn't help clear things up please post a complete test case that demonstrates the error.